# How to find my VirtualBox guest's host IP address from the guest itsefl?

Tags: virtualbox, virtual-machine

Is there a way to discover which is my VirtualBox VM's host machine?
My VM guests only network is a "bridged adapter" (no NAT).
A sample `ifconfig` is:

```
CODE: SELECT ALL   EXPAND VIEW
enp0s9: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 192.168.1.36  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.1.255
        inet6 fe80::f821:6317:c27a:16c6  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether 08:00:27:f6:b5:54  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 6889970  bytes 9898198227 (9.2 GiB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 587306  bytes 43842901 (41.8 MiB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

lo: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING>  mtu 65536
        inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.0.0.0
        inet6 ::1  prefixlen 128  scopeid 0x10<host>
        loop  txqueuelen 1000  (Local Loopback)
        RX packets 1002  bytes 105104 (102.6 KiB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 1002  bytes 105104 (102.6 KiB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

virbr0: flags=4099<UP,BROADCAST,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 192.168.122.1  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.122.255
        ether 52:54:00:73:34:0f  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

Sample `netstat -rn` output:

```
CODE: SELECT ALL   EXPAND VIEW
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags   MSS Window  irtt Iface
0.0.0.0         192.168.1.99    0.0.0.0         UG        0 0          0 enp0s9
192.168.1.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U         0 0          0 enp0s9
192.168.122.0   0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U         0 0          0 virbr0
```

Both Host and Guest machines are Linux CentOS 7.

Comment: What is it that you are looking for? Is this output from the guest? Are you trying to find the IP of the host from the guest?

Comment: look at this [Find out host ip address (from guest vm)](https://forums.virtualbox.org/viewtopic.php?f=1&t=11267)
so you cant, and the VM can have up to 10 vmnics all connected to other virtual networks on the host. and as @Appleoddity asked: what do you want to achieve?

Comment: Yes and yes, @Appleoddity. (@Zina)

Comment: @harrymc, This is not a duplicate of Find the IP address of a VMware ESXi host, as my question is about VitualBox, and not VMware.

Comment: The answer is the same for VitualBox, VMware, Hyper-V etc.

Answer (score 4):

One solution is to define a **host-only network**.

From the VirtualBox GUI, choose `file -> Host Network Manager`
This will create a new window called *Host Network Manager*
If the screen in *Host Network Manager* is empty, click on *create*

[image: add host only network]

The host’s IP will be `192.168.56.1`, namely, the first address in the *host-only network*:

```
$ ifconfig | egrep ':|inet'
enp0s3: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 192.168.56.101  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.56.255
        inet6 fe80::a30b:4c65:13a6:ab5a  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether 08:00:27:99:af:b0  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
enp0s9: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 192.168.1.196  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.1.255
        inet6 fe80::b7d:99d3:7106:46e9  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether 08:00:27:da:3c:5b  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
lo: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING>  mtu 65536
        inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.0.0.0
        inet6 ::1  prefixlen 128  scopeid 0x10<host>
virbr0: flags=4099<UP,BROADCAST,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 192.168.122.1  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.122.255
        ether 52:54:00:73:34:0f  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
```

Comment: Where does your output of `ifconfig` indicate the host’s network address is 192.168.56.1????

Comment: The x.x.x.1 seems to be the convention that VirtualBox uses, @Appleoddity. So, if `ifconfig` indicates that the host-only network is `192.168.56.0`, I assume that it follows that the host is `192.168.56.1`.